# Странный редирект WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт на wordpress, установлен плагин woocommerce (но возможно дело и не в нём). Случайно выяснилось, что есть страница https://example.ru/katalog/test/0 (вместо test может быть что угодно), которая редиректится на https://example.ru/katalog/test/0/ и отдаёт 200 ответ и использует шаблон index.php текущей темы. На странице title от последнего добавленного товара. Страница, например https://example.ru/katalog/test/1 отдаёт 404.

Если зайти на https://example.ru/katalog/0/, то тоже будет ответ 200 и страница с описанием последней добавленной категории.

Куда смотреть хоть? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Редиректит на саму себя (бред)? Тема самописька? Точно цифровые слаги? Что такое katalog и test в сущностях ВП? Исправь вопрос.

Comment: Тема самописаная, да.
katalog - это база категорий товара.
test - всё что угодно, проблема обнаружилась с слагом одной из категорий каталога.